# Laravel URL language prefix with many different sites

Tags: php, laravel, routes, multilingual

I’m currently working on a new website and want to use multi language on different pages and the URL should include the prefix.
This is my goal and should be achieved:

```
Mywebsite/ --> Mywebsite/en
Mywebsite/en --> Should show the main page in en
Mywebsite/de --> Should show the main pahe in de
Mywebsite/en/legal --> Should show legal page in en
Mywebsite/legal --> Should show the legal page in the before selected language and redirect to Mywebsite/en/legal
```

So if the prefix is missing the site should be redirected and show the exact page in the correct language.

I tried to implement this way but not all cases are working.

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
});

Route::get('/legal', function () {
    return redirect(app()->getLocale() . '/legal');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 'middleware' => 'localization'], function($locale) {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('home');
    });

    Route::get('/home', function () {
        return view('home');
    });

    Route::get('/legal', function () {
        return view('legal');
    });

});
```

Localization.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
        return $next($request);
    }
```

- app()->getLocale() does not work at all
- Route::get('/legal', function () is also not working

What is missing or what can I change to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use this Package, The best for what you want to achieve https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

Comment: in your root folder, run `php artisan route:list`, what do you see? and which cases work and which not on requesting page?

Comment: ```Mywebsite/ --> "Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Redirector could not be converted to string"
Mywebsite/en --> works
Mywebsite/de --> works
Mywebsite/en/legal --> works
Mywebsite/legal --> works not, he adds egal to the url Mywebsite/legal/legal```